# Как сделать переход на новое активити?

Tags: android, java

Нашел в недрах гугла какой-то пост, там был способ создания ссылки для текста. Вообще написал, все работает, когда нажимаю на текст, мне надо открыть 2 активити. Как я понял, надо что-то прописать в фильтре в Манифесте, подскажите, что написать там.

Comment: Какой текст? Где он? На сайте? В TextView? Или это кнопка? **Никто ничего не понял**.

Comment: Ну обычный TextView, Html.from тут html код, после этого он становиться ссылкой, когда нажимаешь на ссылку то получается переход в браузер. Вы что в первый раз с сслыками работаете чтоли?))) Это же основа, при клике на гиперссылку кидает в браузер. Так вот мне надо не в браузер а на 2 активити, как сделать это?

Comment: Конечно же не в первый раз. Не передёргивайте. Вопрос некорректно задан. Тут может быть несколько вариантов. В ссылке может быть URL вида "http://site.ru", при нажатии на который можно открыть активити. А можно в ссылке указать приложение. Точно так же можно и на сайте сделать. Какой способ имеете в виду?

Comment: В ссылке указать activity, только тогда надо в фильтре что то написать...а вот что написать то? вот в чем вопрос

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697084/handle-textview-link-click-in-my-android-app

Comment: @ANDRO, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Сделайте вот это и вот это. Должно помочь...    
Чего вы так смотрите? не помогает что ли? А, вы просто не видите, что я вам показал сделать? А я-то думал, что вы тоже телепат, как и все здесь...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос всё ещё не до конца ясен в виду отсутствия кода.

Можно так попробовать:

В манифесте:

```
<activity
        android:name=".Activity"
        android:label="@string/hello_world"
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:host="site.ru" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

В этом случае, при наличии ссылки на "http://site.ru" в TextView должен открыться диалог выбора в чём открыть, в коем будет и приложение с активити, коя описана выше.

Проще же, на мой взгляд, отлавливать клик по ссылке и уже в обработчике делать что угодно, отталкиваясь от ссылки:

```
CharSequence sequence = Html.fromHtml(html);
    SpannableStringBuilder strBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(sequence);
    URLSpan[] urls = strBuilder.getSpans(0, sequence.length(), URLSpan.class);
    for (URLSpan span : urls)
    {
        makeLinkClickable(strBuilder, span);
    }
YOURS_TEXT_VIEW.setText(strBuilder);

protected void makeLinkClickable(SpannableStringBuilder strBuilder, final URLSpan span)
{
    int start = strBuilder.getSpanStart(span);
    int end = strBuilder.getSpanEnd(span);
    int flags = strBuilder.getSpanFlags(span);
    ClickableSpan clickable = new ClickableSpan()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {

             if (span.getURL().equals("http://site.ru")
             {
                             context.startActivity(new Intent(context, Activity.class);
                         }
                    }
            }
strBuilder.setSpan(clickable, start, end, flags);
    strBuilder.removeSpan(span);
}
```

**UPD 0:**

По [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697084/handle-textview-link-click-in-my-android-app) [[@gcoder](/users/9127/gcoder)](/users/9127/gcoder) написан ещё такой вариант. Простейший:

1) В манифесте:

```
<intent-filter>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<data android:scheme="com.package.name" />  
</intent-filter>
```

В этом случае эта активити будет ловить нажатия на все ссылки, в коих вместо "http://" будет "com.package.name://".

Соответственно, если в вашем TextView будет ссылка вида **"com.package.name://что-угодно/ещё-что-нибудь/"** то при её нажатии будет открыта активити.

Comment: Окна выбора быть не должно. Надо просто нажать на ссылку, которая есть в тексте, и после этого должен произойти startActivity, как еще-то проще объяснить. Не понимаю, что вы хотите услышать от меня, то, что вы хотите, или все же то, что я пишу?

Comment: Проще вообще кнопку закинуть и прописать ему setOnClick и все. Если бы так все просто было бы, я бы стал сюда тему создавать...

Comment: Второй блок кода должен аести себя заяаленным образом. Без диалога.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791482/start-activity-intent-on-clicking-text-inside-webview?newreg=b3035ee90e04429ba695b1fd6c55fe64

Почему так нелезья?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, там про WebView, а вы про TextView.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, Как можно попроще словить нажатие нассылку? уж сильно большой код у вас....мне просто надо чтобы по нажатии на ссылку открылась активити и ничего лишнего....

Comment: Обновил ответ, использовав ссылку @gcoder.